# how to put a figure on the side of text?

Tags: floats

I have a figure which does not occupy a lot of horizontal space, and I want to put text on its left side. Is there a way to put a figure environment such that the text naturally flows on the left, instead of the figure environment blocking all horizontal space?

EDIT:

thanks for the reference to wrapfig! wrapfig helps, but I can't seem to get it at the top of the page, and the wrapfigure environment does not accept any such parameter. The PDF file for the package does not mention that. any idea how to place the figure at top? (I would use the [t] flag normally with a figure environment.)

Comment: http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=textflow

Comment: Maybe you'd like to have a look at the following packages: [wrapfig](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/wrapfig), [floatrow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) or [sidenotes](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/sidenotes). Maybe also [snotez](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/snotez).

Comment: Another one to the list: [`cutwin`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cutwin).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package to make it: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig

Comment: This is a link - like answer, rather a comment than a solution.

Comment: thanks! wrapfig helps, but I can't seem to get it at the top of the page, and the wrapfigure environment does not accept any such parameter. The PDF file for the package does not mention that. any idea how to place the figure at top? (I would use the [t] flag normally with a figure environment.)

Answer (score 0):

I think this will solve your problem. In `wrapfig` try set position to C and place the figure before your text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\begin{wrapfigure}{C}{5cm}
\centering
\rule{3cm}{7cm}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1-6]

\end{document}
```